# Ubuntu 12.04 via xrdp keyboard layout cannot change

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout, xrdp

I have a virtually hosted ubuntu server 12.04 on which I installed Unity desktop.  It all works fine except the only keyboard option I have is "US".  This could be due to the fact that ubuntu server was installed with US keyboard (by the virtual machine provider).

I want the keyboard layout to be Canadian-French.  I cannot change the keyboard layout from the GUI/Desktop see pic.

I have the feeling I need to install new layouts, perhaps using apt-get something!  (noob)

SO the questions could be how to add new layouts?  (I have root btw)

[image]

Comment: I have found that the XRDP keyboard layout problem is unsolvable the "easy" way, as things sometimes can be in Linux. Fortunately, there is a workaround, as there is often in Linux. Here is a guide I wrote on creating your own custom keymap for XRDP: http://cloclotron.net/xrdp_keyboard_layout_workaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace keyboard mapping using:

```
 xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-040c.ini
```

If this doesn't work, then replace the content of the file */etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini* (default keyboard mapping en-us) by this *xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-040c.ini* (french). You can find keyboard mapping for other languages in the [doc](https://www.mankier.com/8/xrdp-genkeymap), or create your own using:

```
sudo setxkbmap -layout 'ca' -model logitech_base
```

Check the [help](https://www.mankier.com/1/setxkbmap) for the command above.