# xrdp - how to change keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xrdp

When I open an xrdp session from a Windows 7 machine to my Ubuntu machine, US keyboard layout is utilized. However, my default keyboard layout is different on Ubuntu machine and I want to use it during xrdp sessions. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which keyboard layout would you like to set? Check http://askubuntu.com/a/593944/385763

Comment: I am still working on that, too. This should be a good starting point ➝ http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3858

Comment: What I'm noticed is that even now on Windows 10 with pre-configured Ubuntu 18 image from Hyper-V keyboard layout switching sometimes stops working on Hyper-V VM with Ubuntu from time to time, for example when it resumes after Hyper-V host reboot... In that case issue does not goes away until I reboot VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have installed xrdp, you should have te xrdp-genkeymap installed on your system.  the utility will be located under **/etc/xrdp folder**

To change keyboard layout, you need indeed to issue the xrdp-genkeymap command. 
The command has to be run locally on the ubuntu machine and not from the xrdp session.
issue the following command to use us layout keyboard during your xrdp session 
**sudo xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini**

If you need other language layout, you have to find the correct km-xxx.ini file

Hope this help 
Till next time 
see ya

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to contribute here, since there seems to be little instructions.

Find the language / keyboard input you need from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdesktop/code/1704/tree/rdesktop/trunk/doc/keymap-names.txt)

*So for example fr-be French (Belgium) is 080C.*

Then run these commands to generate the keyboard mapping for your chosen input.

```
xrdp-genkeymap km-080C.ini
```

To copy it in the xrdp folder

```
sudo mv km-080C.ini /etc/xrdp
```

Remember that you must change the permissions of the file, so that it can be used

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/xrdp/km-080C.ini
```

Restart the service and it should work

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Comment: Thankyou Enrico, this issue had been driving me crazy for hours - the extra explanation and info is great

Comment: I got a crash when restarting the service, probably because now services are managed using _systemd_. In this case, what worked for me is `sudo systemctl restart xrdp`

Comment: IMPORTANT: You have to generate the keymap from your normal Ubuntu session, not from under xrdp.

Answer (score 9):

for me it was enough to run next command, in order to set the right keyboard map in X

```
setxkbmap be
```

where you must replace the "be" with your land code. 
You can see the current value with

```
setxkbmap -query
```

Comment: This works, but for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to have this run automatically upon login (my context is ubuntu vm running on a windows 10 host using hyper v with rdp connection)

Comment: I added `setxkbmap be` line to /etc/xrdp/reconnectwm.sh as on reconnect, my session would return to the default us keyboard layout. My sincere thanks from a fellow Belgian.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately none of the above answers completely solved my problem.

After looking into directory `sudo ls /etc/xrdp/` I found out that `.ini` files had more 0 prefixes, so instead I had to do the following, to make it work.

`sudo xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-00000424.ini` (Slovenian layout)

and then additionally edit file `sudo vi /etc/xrdp/xrdp-keyboard.ini` and add the following lines after each section:

```sh
[default_rdp_layouts]
rdp_layout_si=0x00000424

; <rdp layout name> = <X11 keyboard layout value>
[default_layouts_map]
rdp_layout_si=si

[rdp_layouts_map_mac]
rdp_layout_si=si
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: Indeed, xrdp uses the mapping between `default_rdp_layouts` and `default_layouts_map` to know which keyboard layout to use for the X session. If the keyboard code sent by the rdp client is not listed, then it defaults to a "us" layout. Thanks for the answer, it helped fixing my issue with keyboard code 0xa000040c (fr) sent by Windows!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, manipulation with ini files did not work for me. Maximum what I could get is the additional layouts, which are also English. So I ended up with 3  weird named English layouts. What helped is adding this to the *beginning* of the `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` and `/etc/xrdp/reconnectwm.sh` right after the 1st line, example:

```
( sleep 3; setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us,ru -option grp:alt_shift_toggle )&
```

Or if you want to set XRDP keyboard layout from system-wide settings file `/etc/default/keyboard`, which is probably what you want, than put this instead:

```
. /etc/default/keyboard
( sleep 3; setxkbmap ${XKBMODEL:+-model "$XKBMODEL"} ${XKBLAYOUT:+-layout "$XKBLAYOUT"} ${XKBVARIANT:+-variant "$XKBVARIANT"} ${XKBOPTIONS:+-option "$XKBOPTIONS"} )&
```

BTW setting up the system-wide keyboard settings file `/etc/default/keyboard` itself may be done in the following ways:

- Editing it by hand
- With the configuration utility: `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
- With the command line utility: `localectl set-x11-keymap us,ru pc105 , grp:alt_shift_toggle`

Answer (score 1):

Try to **locally** run this code not from xrdp session :

```
xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini
```

Restart xrdp and try .

Comment: There is no xrdp-genkeymap command on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation as k3br, the answer by Enrico didn't work for me, and the solution for me was similar to k3br's answer. However in my case the name of the km-xxxxxxxx.ini file that I got from looking up my keyboard from [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdesktop/code/1704/tree/rdesktop/trunk/doc/keymap-names.txt) from Enrico's answer didn't match the file that xrdp was trying to open upon login.

I used the idea described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251021) to figure out which keyboard file xrdp was trying to open upon login by running the following

```
sudo cat /var/log/xrdp.log | grep key
```

which gave this output:

```
[20220818-16:43:48] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00001009.ini
[20220818-16:43:48] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
```

So in my case xrdp was trying to open km-00001009.ini, couldn't find it so defaulted to km-00000409.ini, which is the US keyboard. I have no idea why xrdp was looking to the km-00001009.ini, since that corresponds to the english (canada) keyboard according to the link above and I am using the french (canada) keyboard. So what I did is I generated the km-00001009.ini file from a non-xrdp session on the ubuntu machine where the keyboard I want was active, using

```
xrdp-genkeymap km-00001009.ini
```

and copied it to /etc/xrdp/, as in Enrico's answer above.

Finally, I had to add the following lines in the /etc/xrdp/xrdp_keyboard.ini file, as xrdp apparently checks that there is a key corresponding to the km file inside that xrdp_keyboard.ini file and bails otherwise:

```
...
[default_rdp_layouts]
...
rdp_layout_fr_ca=0x00001009
...
[default_layouts_map]
...
rdp_layout_fr_ca=ca
...
```

I actually don't know how much the language letters following rdp_layout_ (fr_ca, for french canada in my case) matters, I suspect it doesn't. I also don't know if the "ca" in the rdp_layout_fr_ca=ca matters. ca is the letters for the french canada  keyboard so that's why I put it, but I didn't try with other letters to see if it would work regardless.