# Why do some of the keys not work when connecting to xrdp?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xrdp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04  I have installed xrdp and a number of desktops such as mate and xfce.  I'm able to log in from a Windows machine as well as from other Ubuntu machines.  However, some of the key strokes fail to work from both the Windows client and the Linux clients.

I get the same results from both.  The lower case <kbd>l</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys don't work.  The upper case <kbd>L</kbd> does work from all clients.

I performed this (from: [xrdp - how to change keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412755/xrdp-how-to-change-keyboard-layout)):

```
$ xrdp-genkeymap /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a known issue with xrdp. 
Special keys on keyboard might not be working when connecting through xrdp.  It's possible to fix it by updating the keyboard mapping file used by the xrdp software

To fix your issue, you will need to dump the keyboard layout used when no xrdp connection are performed, them dump the keyboard layout in the xrdp session.  You will then compare both files to get the value representing your special keyboard key and update the keyboard mapping file used by xrdp.

The process is not easy to describe or summarize. To better understand the issue and the possible solution , I recommend you to read the detailed instructions found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3858)

Answer (score 1):

The culprit causing some of the keys not to function in a **Remote Desktop** `xrdp` session is Cairo-Dock.  Many people may not have been able to replicate the issue because they don't use Cairo-Dock.  However, every since Unity came to Ubuntu, I have used Cairo-Dock as my launcher in all my Ubuntu installations.  Being one of the first things installed in a new installation, it was in all my remote desktop attempts.

The fix is to change the Cairo-Dock's offending hotkeys to a different keystroke, or exit Cairo-Dock.